# Why a Groovy script keeps the previous array value?

Tags: arrays, soapui

I have this simple Groovy script (executed from SoapUI):

```
def String[] unsorted
def String[] sorted

unsorted=null
sorted=null

unsorted = ["Lucas", "Fred", "Mary", "Aaron", "Brent"]
log.info("unsorted: ${unsorted}")

sorted = unsorted.sort()
log.info("sorted: ${sorted}")
```

When I execute it the first time, it sorts the unsorted array as expected. However the second time that I run it, the unsorted array is displayed with the sorted values. Even if I reset both arrays to null at the beggining, it keeps the results from the sorted array. Does somebody have an idea why?

This is the output:

[Log Output View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9sa.png)
[image]

Comment: Wow! this is very interesting. Not sure if soapui is intelligent to cache the script results? It is not reproducible in plain groovy though.